# Equal height for each product in woocomerce

Tags: html, css

I am using a theme that display my products 3 in a row.The problem is that products do not have the same height.I tried to add **grid-auto-rows: 1fr;** and **display: flex;** in **.content-inner.products[data-grid] .product** but not worked.Maybe i don t hit the right container.. i don t know. Bellow is an image with my website [Products with not same height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRyFz.png) and here is a link with [woocomerce product page](https://smartphonerepair.be/product-category/computer-herstelling/macbook-herstellen/macbook-12-2015-2017-a1534-herstellen/).
I need equal height.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,so it was about title lenght .On some products was bigger and smaller on some of them.
So i solved my problem with the code bellow :

.woocommerce .products li h3, .woocommerce .products li .woocommerce-loop-product__title {
height: 65px !important ;
}

Comment: Be aware that with this solution headers that exceed the fixed height of 65px will layer over the content that follows below.